# R - aggregate results in disparity between names(data) and columns in head(data)

Tags: r, aggregate, head, names

I have a dataset of long format with 3 factors (`strain`, `genotype`, `region`) and 1 value (`volume`). This dataset is called `individualData`.  Basically what I'm trying to do is calculate the mean and standard deviation of volume for every combination of `strain * genotype * region`, with the exception of those combinations without any data (since genotype labels depend on the strain).  It seems like I've been able to do this with the following command, since it produces the expected number of rows:

```
  summaryData = aggregate( .~strain:genotype:region, individualData, FUN = function(x) c(mn=mean(x), stdev=sd(x)))
```

The problem is that `head(summaryData)` gives me 5 columns (`volume` is replaced with `volume.mn` and `volume.stdev`), as I would have expected, but `names(summaryData)` or `colnames(summaryData)` gives me only 4 columns -- namely, my original columns.  How do I refer to the columns properly?  I just want to collapse this into a `data.frame` that I understand how to work with.  Anyone with more experience with the `aggregate` function know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here's some reproducible sample data which i'm assuming matches your structure

```
set.seed(15)
individualData <- data.frame(
    volume = runif(120),
    expand.grid(region=1:2, genotype=1:3, strain=1:2)
)
```

Then you're running

```
summaryData = aggregate( .~strain:genotype:region, individualData, 
    FUN = function(x) c(mn=mean(x), stdev=sd(x)))
```

and if you look at the structure of what's returned, you get

```
str(summaryData)
# 'data.frame':   12 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ strain  : int  1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
#  $ genotype: int  1 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 2 2 ...
#  $ region  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
#  $ volume  : num [1:12, 1:2] 0.526 0.409 0.407 0.445 0.566 ...
#   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   .. ..$ : NULL
#   .. ..$ : chr  "mn" "stdev"
```

so `aggregate` has actually stuffed a matrix into the `volume` column. You can index these values with

```
summaryData$volume[,"mn"]
summaryData$volume[,"stdev"]
```

or turn it into a proper data.frame with

```
summaryData <- do.call(data.frame, summaryData)
summaryData$volume.mn
summaryData$volume.stdev
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you.  I was baffled until I found out that `data.frame` columns can be of type `matrix`.